# can't see using VPN gateway by default option in windows 7

Tags: vpn

I've created a vpn server under windows 7. My phone connects succesfully but I don't have internet connection. I've readen that I must disable option "use default gateway". I've gone to incoming connection,tcp v4 but I can't see that option.
Someone could help me please?
Thanks!

Comment: Windows 7 - are you using PPtP VPN?  That is not split tunnel so all Internet goes through the tunnel. It appears there is no internet outside the tunnel.

Comment: Please uncheck "Use default gateway on remote network" in the client VPN settings under IPv4 settings instead of incoming connection.